# Modifying Dijkstra's Algorithm to an A* implementation

Tags: c, implementation, graph-algorithm, dijkstra, a-star

I'm in the process of creating a maze simulation of a mouse running through a maze.  Dijkstra's algorithm is great and all but isn't particularly effected when cats are involved, which is why I'm trying to modify my existing Dijkstra implementation to an A* search with a heuristic for avoiding the cats which move throughout the maze.

The problem I'm having while I look through some pseudocode is I am unsure of what structures are equivalent or what will I need to introduce to get this working. Can anyone provide any tips or nudges in the right direction?

```
struct path_node *shortestPath(float A[GsizeSqr][GsizeSqr], int xi, int yi, int xf, int yf)
{
    /*
    Solves for the shortest path between grid point (xi,yi) and (xf,yf)
    on the graph encoded by A using Dijkstra's shortest path method.

    The shortest path is returned as a linked list of nodes to be visited.

    Keep track of visited nodes, and the predecessor
    for each node that has been explored while computing the shortest path.*/

    if (xi<0||xi>=Gsize&&yi<0&&yi>=Gsize||xf<0||xf>=Gsize||yf<0||yf>=Gsize)
    {
        fprintf(stderr,"shortestPath(): Endpoint(s) outside of the graph!\n");
        return(NULL);
    }

    int i, j, pCount, findN, row, col, icnt, stNode, finNode, xcnt, ycnt;
    finNode = yf * ceil(sqrt(GsizeSqr)) + xf; //index of start node given its row and col value
    stNode = yi * ceil(sqrt(GsizeSqr)) + xi; //index of finish node given its row and col value

    int p[GsizeSqr]; //predecessors
    int d[GsizeSqr]; //distance from source
    int flags[GsizeSqr]; //(0, 1) for unvisited, visited)

    int g_score[GsizeSqr];
    int f_score[GsizeSqr];

    PriorityQueue Q; //Initialize priority queue that stores (priority, key) values
    Q = init_heap(GsizeSqr);    

    path_node *start; //Maintain a pointer to the starting node
    start = newPathNode(xi, yi);
    start->next = NULL;

    //Initialize p and d with infinity and NULL values (note: -1 means null and 1000000 means inf)
    for(i=0; i < GsizeSqr; i++){
        p[i] = -1;
        d[i] = 10000000;
        flags[i] = 0;
    }

    for(i=0; i < GsizeSqr; i++){
        node in;
        in = create_node(10000000, i);
        enqueue(Q, in);
    }

    //(Note: PQ uses 0 as a sentinel node to make calculating left, right, and parents easier, elements begin at 1)
    decrease_priority(Q, stNode+1, 0); //setting start node in PQ.
    d[stNode] = 0;

    g_score[stNode] = 0;
    //For my heuristic, I'm thinking just using manhattan distances between mouse and cat agents
    f_score[stNode] = g_score[stNode] + heuristic(xi, yi, xf, yf);

    while(Q->heap_size != 1){ //while Q not empty
        node u;
        u = dequeue(Q);
        flags[u.key] = 1;

        //For each adjacent node A[u.key][i]
        for(i=0; i < GsizeSqr; i++){
            if(A[u.key][i] != 0){
                findN = find_node(Q, i);
                if(flags[i] == 0){ //If it is unvisited and new path distance is shorter
                    if(findN != 0 && (d[i] >= A[u.key][i] + d[u.key])){ //reset values and update PQ and mark visited
                        d[i] = A[u.key][i] + d[u.key];
                        p[i] = u.key;                       
                        flags[i] = 1;
                        decrease_priority(Q, findN, d[i]);
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }

    // Begin selectively filling our LL with values from p[]
    icnt = finNode;
    appendLL(start, xf, yf);
    while(icnt != stNode){
        icnt = p[icnt];
        xcnt = icnt % (int)ceil(sqrt(GsizeSqr));
        ycnt = icnt / (int)ceil(sqrt(GsizeSqr));
        appendLL(start, xcnt, ycnt);
    }

    clean_heap(Q);
    return reverseLL(start);
}
```

Comment: Do you have an actual, more specific question?

Comment: More specifically, I'm wondering if there is a way to convert dijkstra's algorithm into A* without rewriting the whole thing?

Comment: no rewrite necessary. e.g. you'll need lat,lon of every point and a distance function. Dijkstra is just the algo with estimated distance to goal == 0. Have a look: https://github.com/karussell/GraphHopper/blob/master/core/src/main/java/de/jetsli/graph/routing/AStar.java

Answer (score 1):

You possibly already know this, but the only theoretical difference between A* and Dijkstra's algorithm in terms of best-first search is the cost function f(n).  Dijkstra's algorithm is `f(n) = g(n)` whilst A* is `f(n) = g(n) + h(n)`.  Read [AIMA](http://aima.cs.berkeley.edu/) for details.

In terms of your code, it currently stores `g(n) = A[u.key][i] + d[u.key]` in `d[i]`, so you need to change it store g(n) + h(n).  You don't need those new `g_score` and `f_score` variables, just add the heuristic to the end of that line and the initialization of `d[stNode]`.